# Java EJB and .NET Adapter

Tags: .net, jakarta-ee, transactions

We are writing an Adapter in .NET world which would like to communicate with EJB hosted on JEE server, we would like to propagate transactions between .NET container to JEE so that we can control it from .NET environment. We found IIOP.NET is there any alternative for this?

Comment: Just make the EJB a webservice and be done with it. It needn't be too complicated

Comment: How would we handle transactions with web services? How about when we deploy EJB in multi app server environment?

Comment: If you don't accost the partner (in this case @kolossus) in the very begining of the comment, he or she won't be notified about your message. Here is the example : http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ejb/ejb_web_services.htm If you use required/mandatory trx attributes the container will join to the client side transatcion.